# Disable panning while zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I switched from google maps api for iOS to here maps api for iOS . I would like to disable panning/scrolling of map while zooming in order to keep gps location of centre point same. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
[MPAMapView disableMapGestures:] apis to disable panning/scrolling. 
Details could be found @ https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios/topics/map-gestures.html

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this use case using a combination of `NMAMapGestureDelegate` and `NMAMapViewDelegate`.

For example, you can implement the `NMAMapGestureDelegate` `- (void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didReceivePinch:(float)pinch atLocation:(CGPoint)location;` handler method to add some extra code to disable the gestures you wish to block. And then re-enable the gestures once the pinch gesture has ended.

Something like this should do the trick, you may have to play with the implementation a bit to get it working how you would like:

```
- (void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didReceivePinch:(float)pinch atLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    [mapView disableMapGestures:(NMAMapGestureTypePan | NMAMapGestureTypeTwoFingerPan)];

    // execute default pinch behaviour
    [mapView.defaultGestureHandler mapView:mapView didReceivePinch:pinch atLocation:location];
}
```

...

```
- (void)mapViewDidEndMovement:(NMAMapView *)mapView
{
    [mapView enableMapGestures:NMAMapGestureTypeAll];
}
```

You can look at `NMAMapView` `- (NSInteger)respondToEvents:(NSInteger)events withBlock:(NMAMapEventBlock)block` as well. It's possible responding to the `NMAMapEventGestureEnded` event using `respondToEvents` may work better for your use case.

More Information:

[Map Gestures](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/map-gestures.html)

[NMAMapGestureDelegate](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/protocolnmamapgesturedelegate-p.html)

[NMAMapViewDelegate](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/protocolnmamapviewdelegate-p.html)

[Map Event Blocks](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/maps.html#maps__map-events)

Comment: I already tried disabling gesture while performing pinch. Issue is that if you pinch on edges, i.e not in centre of map. Map centre moves away. In google maps iOS sdk same can be achieved by allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom property of gmsuisettings class.

Comment: It sounds like you should try using `NMAMap` `transformCenter` and `fixedMapCenterOnMapRotateZoom`

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for you quick responses. Although fixedMapCenterOnMapRotateZoom property is defined in documentation but unfortunately it looks like this property has been removed in SDK ver 3.1.1

Comment: Are you using the HERE premium SDK or starter SDK? The `fixedMapCenterOnMapRotateZoom` API appears to only be in the premium SDK.

Comment: I'm using premium sdk 90 day trial.

Comment: You're right, the API is not present in the 3.1.1 release, sorry about that. It will be added in 3.2 release coming in July. Also, `transformCenter` will not work for your use case as it does not apply to gestures.

Comment: Thanks for your support Andrew. Much appreciated.