# Here maps JS API — disable panning while zooming

Tags: javascript, here-api

This is the same question but for the JS API — 
[Disable panning while zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915704/disable-panning-while-zooming)

So, i have a map centered on lat/lng coordinates — i don't want them to change while zooming with two fingers.

Is there an option to disable map panning while zooming?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to disable map panning, also known as "dragging". Here is how you can do it:

```
const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(
  new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map)
);

behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
```